# How can print a list I in columns with textwrap?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries which contains product information.
I would like to print each value from dictionaries in columns and textwrap values which exceed the length of a column.

Here is what I have so far, It seems like str.format() doesn't add space padding when a string is wrapped. How can I put them in columns ?

list:

```
product_list = [{'num': 1, 'brands': 'Auchan', 'product_name': 'Pain de mie complet spécial sandwich', 'id': 213, 'cat_id': 3, 'nutrition_grade_fr': 'A'}, {'num': 2, 'brands': 'Bjorg', 'product_name': 'Pain complet 3 céréales', 'id': 211, 'cat_id': 3, 'nutrition_grade_fr': 'A'}, {'num': 3, 'brands': 'Brioche Pasquier', 'product_name': 'Biscotte au son, La Biscotte Blé Complet', 'id': 243, 'cat_id': 3, 'nutrition_grade_fr': 'A'}, {'num': 4, 'brands': 'Brioche Pasquier,Pasquier', 'product_name': 'La Biscotte Equilibre (36 biscottes)', 'id': 226, 'cat_id': 3, 'nutrition_grade_fr': 'A'}, {'num': 5, 'brands': 'Carrefour', 'product_name': 'Pain azyme', 'id': 299, 'cat_id': 3, 'nutrition_grade_fr': 'A'}, {'num': 6, 'brands': 'Carrefour', 'product_name': 'Spécial sandwich Complet 088€', 'id': 287, 'cat_id': 3, 'nutrition_grade_fr': 'A'}, {'num': 7, 'brands': 'Carrefour discount', 'product_name': 'Pain de mie Sandwich complet', 'id': 262, 'cat_id': 3, 'nutrition_grade_fr': 'A'}, {'num': 8, 'brands': 'Céréal Bio', 'product_name': 'Tartines croquantes multicéréales - riz, sarrasin & quinoa', 'id': 258, 'cat_id': 3, 'nutrition_grade_fr': 'A'}]
```

code:

```
for item in product_list:
    menu = '{} - {}'.format(item['brands'], item['product_name'])
    menu = textwrap.fill(menu, width=60)
    print('{:>2}. {:<60} Score : {}'.format(
    item['num'], menu, item['nutrition_grade_fr']))
```

result:

```
1. Bio Village,Marque Repère - 36 biscottes au germe de blé     Score : A
2. Bjorg - Pain complet 3 céréales                              Score : A
3. Brioche Pasquier - Biscotte au son, La Biscotte Blé Complet  Score : A
4. Brioche Pasquier,Pasquier - La Biscotte Equilibre (36
biscottes) Score : A
5. Carrefour - Pain azyme                                       Score : A
6. Carrefour - Spécial sandwich Complet 088€                    Score : A
7. Carrefour discount - Pain de mie Sandwich complet            Score : A
8. Céréal Bio - Tartines croquantes multicéréales - riz,
sarrasin & quinoa Score : A
```

What I want:

```
1. Bio Village,Marque Repère - 36 biscottes au germe de blé     Score : A
2. Bjorg - Pain complet 3 céréales                              Score : A
3. Brioche Pasquier - Biscotte au son, La Biscotte Blé Complet  Score : A
4. Brioche Pasquier,Pasquier - La Biscotte Equilibre (36
   biscottes)                                                   Score : A
5. Carrefour - Pain azyme                                       Score : A
6. Carrefour - Spécial sandwich Complet 088€                    Score : A
7. Carrefour discount - Pain de mie Sandwich complet            Score : A
8. Céréal Bio - Tartines croquantes multicéréales - riz,
   sarrasin & quinoa                                            Score : A
```

Solved :

```
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=50 subsequent_indent='    ')
line_length = 50
for item in product_list:
    menu = '{} - {}'.format(item['brands'], item['product_name'])
    curr_length = len(menu)
    menu =  wrapper.fill(menu)
    lastline = wrapper.wrap(menu)
    space = 0
    if len(lastline) > 1:
        if len(lastline[-1]) < line_length:
            space = line_length - len(lastline[-1]) + 4
        print('{:>2}. {:<50}{} Score : {}'.format(
            item['num'], menu, " "*space, item['nutrition_grade_fr']))
```

Thank you ukemi, you gave me an idea to start.
Does anyone have a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the indentation on subsequent lines by changing the `subsequent_indent` parameter:

```
...
menu = textwrap.fill(menu, width=60, subsequent_indent="    ") #4 spaces, length of " x. "
...
```

```
 1. Auchan - Pain de mie complet spécial sandwich               Score : A
 2. Bjorg - Pain complet 3 céréales                             Score : A
 3. Brioche Pasquier - Biscotte au son, La Biscotte Blé Complet Score : A
 4. Brioche Pasquier,Pasquier - La Biscotte Equilibre (36
    biscottes) Score : A
 5. Carrefour - Pain azyme                                      Score : A
 6. Carrefour - Spécial sandwich Complet 088€                   Score : A
 7. Carrefour discount - Pain de mie Sandwich complet           Score : A
 8. Céréal Bio - Tartines croquantes multicéréales - riz,
    sarrasin & quinoa Score : A
```

You may need to use slightly more complicated logic to fix the right alignment of subsequent lines though, something along the lines of:

```
line_length = 60

for item in product_list:
    menu = '{} - {}'.format(item['brands'], item['product_name'])
    menu = textwrap.fill(menu, width=line_length, subsequent_indent="    ")
    curr_length = len(menu)
    if curr_length > line_length:
        space = 2*line_length - curr_length #Computes space needed for overflowing lines
    else:
        space = 0

    print('{:>2}. {:<60}{} Score : {}'.format(item['num'], menu, " "*space, item['nutrition_grade_fr']))
```

```
 1. Auchan - Pain de mie complet spécial sandwich               Score : A
 2. Bjorg - Pain complet 3 céréales                             Score : A
 3. Brioche Pasquier - Biscotte au son, La Biscotte Blé Complet Score : A
 4. Brioche Pasquier,Pasquier - La Biscotte Equilibre (36
    biscottes)                                                  Score : A
 5. Carrefour - Pain azyme                                      Score : A
 6. Carrefour - Spécial sandwich Complet 088€                   Score : A
 7. Carrefour discount - Pain de mie Sandwich complet           Score : A
 8. Céréal Bio - Tartines croquantes multicéréales - riz,
    sarrasin & quinoa                                           Score : A
```

**Note:** Not actual output, running your original code I was not able to replicate your results - the lines were not correctly right aligned. Each 'score' bit is one or two spaces to the left or right.

Comment: Looks like it does not count subsequent indentation.